# Trigger action from button in odoo qweb

Tags: python, django, xml, odoo, qweb

I'm trying to run a view from stock.picking view and it's ok when I call it using menuitem, but when i'm trying to replace menuitem by button, it's not triggered.

In my .xml

```
<menuitem name="My Element"  id="menu_elem" action="my_action_name"/> this was working well.
```

But that one is wrong. For example,I don't want to call the myMethod from my model,but it's required to have name="". So when I click on my button, it calls the method  and I hadn't my action triggered like in menuitem

```
<record id="myId1" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">stock.picking.form.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_picking_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <field name="state" position="before">
        <button name="myMethod"  string="My Element" action="my_action_name" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
    </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

So is there a way to have only triggered action without the use of model method, like in menuitem?

Comment: change this `type="action"` when type is equal to object odoo will try to call a method with that name in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use compute function instead of using action.
compute = "my_action_name"